# поставить VPN на VPS и пустить через него трафик сервера Луникс

Tags: ubuntu, vps, vpn

День добрый! Задача поставить статический ип (и обойти ограничения) на сервер с Убунту 20, для этого поднимаю ВПН на ВПС, настраиваю проксирование на основном сервере, но ип все равно отображается как динамический и трафик не идет через ВПН. Есть может какие то гайды почитать, разобраться? или подскажет кто-то что-то :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, что на сервере динамический IP-адрес и вы хотите через арендованный VPS пустить и входящий, и исходящий трафик на свой сервер и из своего сервера?

Comment: Ответы на данный вопрос скорее всего будут основаны на личном *субъективном* опыте, стоит исправить вопрос так, чтобы ответы на него были исключительно *объективные*. Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1475094/edit).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю всех деталей автора, но делать интерфейс VPN-подключения по умолчанию для исходящего трафика не стоит. Есть риск потерять удалённый доступ к серверу. А так это вполне реально.

**Настройки сети сервера**

Итак, представим, что сетевой интерфейс на нашем сервере имеет название `eth0` (как его узнать - `ifconfig`), а адрес в локальной сети нашего сервера `10.0.1.10`, шлюз - `10.0.1.1`, пул адресов `10.0.1.2-10.0.1.254`

**Поднимаете свой VPN-сервер на арендованном VPS. Можно взять самый дешёвый VPS, а за основу использовать `pptpd` (хотя можно рассмотреть и более безопасные варианты)**

Гайдов как поднять pptpd в интернете уйма, так что здесь это расписывать не буду

**Настройка нашего pptpd на VPS**

Для удобства на стороне pptp-сервера давайте сделаем адрес клиента (я так понимаю, он будет у вас всего один) в виртуальной сети `10.0.2.10`, а адрес VPN-сервера (то есть шлюз) в виртуальной сети у нас будет `10.0.2.1`

**Создаём подключение к нашему VPN-серверу на стороне домашнего сервера**

Идём в `/etc/ppp/peers` и там создаём файл подключения и назовём его myvpn. Пробуете подключиться `pon myvpn`. Видите интерфейс `ppp0` в `ifconfig`? Значит подключились, проверяете `ping 10.0.2.10`. Если пинг есть, идёте дальше

**Настройка iproute2 и netplan**

То, что вы хотите провернуть, можно реализовать через таблицы маршрутизации. Идём в `/etc/iproute2` и открываем `rt_tables`. Создадим в ней две таблицы. Первая для eth0, вторая для ppp0

```
801 801
800 800
```

Первое число - приоритет таблицы, второе - название. Сделаем и то, и другое одинаковыми. Должно получиться что-то вроде такого:

```
#
# reserved values
#
255 local
254 main
253 default
0   unspec
#
# local
#
#1  inr.ruhep
801 801
800 800
```

Сохраняем файл и теперь идём в `/etc/netplan`. Там должен быть файл конфигурации сетей. Я не знаю, как он у вас называется, но у меня он называется `01-netcfg.yaml`.

По умолчанию там следующие настройки:

```yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Обязательно сделайте бэкап настроек. Теперь рассмотрим пример настроек того, чего вы хотите:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ppp0: # задаём настройки интерфейсу vpn-подключения
      addresses: 
      - 10.0.2.10/32 # зададим ему статический ip-адрес в виртуальной сети
      gateway4: 10.0.2.1 # шлюз (ip-адрес vpn-сервера в виртуальной сети)
      mtu: 1496 #
      nameservers: 
        addresses: 
        - 8.8.8.8 
        - 8.8.4.4 
        search: [] 
      routes: # скажем, что весь исходящий трафик должен идти через 10.0.2.1
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0 
          via: 10.0.2.1 
          metric: 50 # ... с метрикой 50
          table: 800 
      routing-policy: 
        - from: 10.0.2.10 
          table: 800 
          priority: 100
    eth0: # теперь основной интерфейс
      addresses:
      - 10.0.1.10/24 # также зададим ему статический айпишник в локальной сети
      mtu: 1500
      gateway4: 10.0.1.1 # адрес роутера/шлюза
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
      routes:  # скажем, что весь исходящий трафик должен идти через 10.0.1.1
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 10.0.1.1
          metric: 100 # но здесь ему зададим метрику выше, чем у ppp0, чтобы весь исходящий трафик по умолчанию шёл именно через eth0
          table: 801
      routing-policy:
        - from: 10.0.1.10
          table: 801
          priority: 200
```

Вводим `netplan apply`, потом проверяем `route -n`. Результат должен получиться примерно таким:

```
root@myserver:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
root@myserver:~#
```

Теперь попробуем по апишке проверить наши IP-адреса поинтерфейсно.

```
root@myserver:~# curl --interface eth0 https://api.myip.com
{"ip":"ваш.динамический.ip.адрес","country":"Russian Federation","cc":"RU"}root@myserver:~#
```

```
root@myserver:~# curl --interface ppp0 https://api.myip.com
{"ip":"публичный.адрес.vpn.сервера","country":"Russian Federation","cc":"RU"}root@myserver:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете openVPN, то чтобы весь трафик шёл через него надо сделать следующее:

Или в серверном конфиге добавить пуш маршрута:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

Или в клиентском конфиге добавить этот маршрут:

```
redirect-gateway def1
```

Так же на стороне сервера надо разрешить этот трафик на фаерволе, настроив маскарадинг.

```bash
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Где сеть `10.8.0.0` это та из которой по умолчанию выдаются ip vpn клиентам, а `eth0` это интерфейс, через который vps сервер смотрит в интернет (у вас может быть другой).